# Completely removing apache + phpmyadmin + php from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am trying to completely remove apache + phpmyadmin + php from my Ubuntu operating system. For phpmyadmin i tried

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin
```

but the files were still in the /etc/ folder. So I tried

```
 sudo rm -rf phpmyadmin
```

However I am not sure if this does the job or still leaves stuff behind?

for Apache I opened the Ubuntu Software centre and tried to uninstall all the apache components but I can still go to localhost and it works? I also tried the same autoremove command but localhost still works.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `--purge` like this

```
apt-get --purge remove PACKAGE
```

in order to remove configuration files when you remove packages.
It works even with `autoremove`.

For further information you can read

```
man apt-get
```

(obviously you need root privileges)

Answer (score 2):

Run the following:

> sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-auth-mysql phpmyadmin
>
> sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
>
> sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils
>   apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove

It will flush out all stuffs behind the scene. ):